# Doctrine Query Builder not registering parameter?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, query-builder

I have the following code which is throwing the exception `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`. Yet when I print the registered parameters, my parameter is showing up.

```
public function getUnitPriceFor($entityType,$entityID,$qty,$configuration_id)
{
    $this->qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $this->qb   ->select($this->_entities[$entityType]['select'])
                // for Base this would be ->select(array('t','c','w','g'))
                // for the other cases below, like website, it's array('t','w')
                ->from('AcmeBundle:PriceTier', 't');

    switch($entityType) :
        case 'base' :
            $this->qb   ->leftJoin('t.customers','c')
                        ->leftJoin('t.customergroups','g')
                        ->leftJoin('t.websites','w');
        break;
        case 'website' :
            $this->qb   ->join('t.websites','w','WITH','w.id = '.$entityID);
        break;
        case 'custgrp' :
            $this->qb   ->join('t.customergroups','g','WITH','g.id = '.$entityID);
        break;
        case 'cust' :
            $this->qb   ->join('t.customers','t','WITH','t.id = '.$entityID);
        break;
    endswitch;

    $this->qb           ->where('t.printconfiguration = :configuration_id');
    $this->qb           ->setParameter('configuration_id', $configuration_id);

    print_r( $this->qb->getParameters() );

    $dql = $this->qb->getDQL();

    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getArrayResult());
    echo"</pre>";
}
```

Printing `$this->qb->getParameters();` shows me `Array ( [configuration_id] => 1 )`, and removing my where and set parameter clauses prevents the exception from occurring. Finally, (and get this), if I remove my where clause but keep the parameter set, no exception occurs. I'm rather confused.

Comment: Does the exception occur with each 'case' or only certain one(s)? Also, have you tried passing $configuration_id directly to your WHERE clause rather than using setParameter()?

Comment: Ah, the other cases would have thrown semantical errors due to the select statement -- I've corrected that, and yes, still an exception with any case. I did try `where('t.printconfiguration = :configuration_id')->setParameter('configuration_id', $configuration_id);` and the same exception still occurred. I could pass it directly like I did in the `case` statements, but that pretty much defeats the purpose of using PDO...

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Could you explain what you mean by "defeats the purpose of using PDO?" I'm not disagreeing -- I've just been passing in my parameters directly to save a little code, and am curious if there's a reason why I shouldn't be doing this. Happy to discuss in chat if it's easier.

Comment: The above functionality is mainly used for prepared statements and stored procedures. It also has some inherent sql injection protection. [Here's the snippet from the PHP manual about prepared statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) Last, [this little tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) has a section about placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `$dql = $this->qb->getDQL();` will not pass parameters.

I needed to change

```
$dql = $this->qb->getDQL();

echo"<pre>";
print_r($this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getArrayResult());
echo"</pre>";
```

**to**

```
$query = $this->qb->getQuery();

echo"<pre>";
print_r($query->getArrayResult());
echo"</pre>";
```